# Unorthodox definition of semi-abelian category

Tags: category-theory, additive-categories

I recently stumbled upon the book *Derived Functors in Functional Analysis* by Wengenroth. In it, he defines semi-abelian categories quite differently from the [nlab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/semi-abelian+category):

> An $\mathsf{Ab}$-category $\mathsf A$ is called semi-abelian if it admits binary products and every arrow $f$ has a kernel and a cokernel, and the induced arrow $\mathrm{Coim}\rightarrow \mathrm{Im}f$ is a bimorphism.

Is there a standard term, or systematic study of such categories?

Comment: I don't think this is equivalent to the standard definition.

Comment: Semi-abelian categories according to nLab (e.g. the category of groups) don't have to be enriched over $\bf Ab$.